# Formatting issues with SVG images in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-animations

I'm trying to make a horizontal scrolling banner animation with different SVG images with the help of HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I want the animation to look similar to what the achievements animation looks like on [Lando Norris' website](https://landonorris.com/).

Since I have little to zero experience in JavaScript I searched for a horizontal banner animation and found [this](https://codepen.io/dgca/pen/dpGLaK). Then I proceeded to replace

```
<div class="sample-item-3"></div>
```

with

```
<img src="link to the svg image on wordpress" class="sample-item">
```

and then changed corresponding css code

```
.sample-item {
  width: auto;
  height: 125px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

I set width to auto because the svg images have different heigh to width ratios and I wanted all of them to be the same height.

The problem now is that the images don't format properly ([screenshot of the images when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic2AB.png)). I can fix this by changing the width to a specific value like 125px. The problem then is though that due to different height to width ratios of the svg images they become unequal (different heights).

As I mentioned before I'm not too familiar with JavaScript so I don't know if that has to do with anything and if it does I wouldn't know how to fix it. So far I've only tried to fix it with CSS though to no avail.

Rest of the code can be found at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/dgca/pen/dpGLaK) (I only changed the mentioned code)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The wreaths in that banner are done using individual svgs for each side of the wreath and the title text is put into containers that are sized and then placed into the scroller. There's a lot of formatting going on there. If you right-click on one of the wreaths and inspect it, you can see there's quite a bit of layout being done which is why it looks so good and functions so well. If you're planning to do this strictly using images, it may just be a matter of setting an explicit height and making the width automatic with a minimum value like so: https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/onez2sdL/

Comment: I've tried that but the formatting doesn't seem to work properly. Could you please take a look if something else might cause the problem?

https://pastebin.com/CB8Y9X6a

Comment: How are you creating and exporting your SVGs? It looks like you tried to put everything on one text line but some of them are too long and don't fit so they're wrapping themselves. You'll need to make sure that each one has enough space to fit if it needs two lines of text. In this case, I broke up your SVG code so the words that would have extended past the wreaths are on their own line. https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/qzx3ktbc/1/

Comment: I use Adobe Illustrator. When I designed the graphics the wreaths were far apart enough for the text to fit in between them. Now that I look at the exported graphics the text indeed wraps itself. I'm not sure what may cause this.
[Imgur link](https://imgur.com/a/4jSAjcK)

Comment: Before you export, make a copy of the graphic group and hide it as a backup, then convert your text to outlines. I don't know what version you're in but typically it's Type -> Create Outlines. It looks like you're losing your font face in the process of exporting but if you convert to outlines the letters become vector objects so the font is irrelevant (you just won't be able to modify the words, hence the need for a backup!).

Comment: I think you're a genius and just cracked the code. I still gotta export a few graphics and insert them into code to fully test it but I think that indeed that was the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries, glad we could get it figured out! Best of luck!

Comment: It did indeed work! Creating the outlines fixed all the formatting/styling issues. One last problem I have though is that the animation doesn't show all the images as an infinite carousel but restarts to the beginning after 10ish seconds. You can see it on the [website](https://pawelosfpv.com) or on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stackoverflowhelpme/1kvd084o/3/). It works as it is on safari but not on Firefox. What seems to fix the issue for firefox is to set the width of the .sample-item to something specific like 125px. The problem then is though that all the images are different sizes.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the transition script itself, not necessarily the images or the class. Even with the fixed-width on Firefox, I'm still seeing the restart. Out of curiosity, is there a reason you did this with JS? The one on the page you were emulating is actually just a 5 minute transition, so long that no normal person would even catch it when it restarts. I'm just wondering because if you're that good at JS you might be able to help me with my most recent question.

Comment: The transition restarts for me after only like 10ish seconds when using Firefox. I'd prefer it to be an "infinite" transition. Regarding my skills in JS I'm sorry to disappoint you, I have none. I just copied the code from [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dgca/pen/dpGLaK). There's no reason that I'm using JS. I'm just not skilled enough to create this transition by myself.

Comment: No worries! Figured it was worth a shot. :) You could actually do this with a keyframe animation and use the 5 minutes for the timing like the site you're trying to emulate. I can't imagine somebody starring at this long enough to see the snap when the animation runs again: https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/w1Loczqf/21/ It may not be technically infinite but I don't see it being worth the trouble to make it work in JS if you're not well-versed in it.